# Error: Creating a Formula field referencing another Formula field

Tags: formula-field, governorlimits

I'm using the following formula in order to show color coding:

[image]

And the content of CS_CaseAge__c are as:

> IF(ISNULL(ClosedDate), (FLOOR(( NOW()- CreatedDate)*24)) 
>   +
>   ROUND((((
>   ((Now() - CreatedDate)*24)-
>   FLOOR((Now() - CreatedDate)*24))
>   *60)/100),2), 
>    (FLOOR(( ClosedDate- CreatedDate)*24)) 
>   +
>   ROUND((((
>   ((ClosedDate - CreatedDate)*24)-
>   FLOOR((ClosedDate - CreatedDate)*24))
>   *60)/100),2))

Do we need to perform the above operation in a different manner? If so what it should be otherwise let me know how I may reduce to 5,000 characters limit.

**EDIT:** Formula used

> IF(CS_CaseAge__c>0 && CS_CaseAge__c<=12, IMAGE('/resource/CS_GreenIMG', "green", 20, 50), IF(CS_CaseAge__c>12 && CS_CaseAge__c<=50, IMAGE('/resource/CS_YellowIMG', "yellow", 20, 50), IF(CS_CaseAge__c>24, IMAGE('resource/CS_RedIMG', "red", 20, 50), IMAGE('resource/CS_RedIMG', "red", 20, 50))))

Comment: Could you post the formula rather than including a picture of it? It will be easier for people to provide answers by copying and pasting the code. Thanks

Comment: Please see the edits.

Comment: Is the logic supposed to be 0 - 12 = green image, 13 - 24 = yellow image, 25 and above = red? You have it as 0 - 12 = green image, 13 - 50 = yellow image, 25 and above = red. Its not clear what the 25 to 50 range should be.

Comment: Absolutely right, this is the problem statement I want to achieve using formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to achieve the requirement below then you could consider rewriting your logic so that `CS_CaseAge__c` isn't used as much.

> 0 - 12 = green image, 13 - 24 = yellow image, 25 and above = red

If you use the logic below then you will only be calling `CS_CaseAge__c` 3 times (instead of 5) in total and will achieve the exact same thing.

```
if (CaseAge >= 25) red
if (CaseAge >= 13) yellow
if (CaseAge >= 0) green
else red
```

Here's how the updated formula would look

```
IF(CS_CaseAge__c >= 25, IMAGE('resource/CS_RedIMG', "red", 20, 50),
IF(CS_CaseAge__c >= 13, IMAGE('resource/CS_YellowIMG', "yellow", 20, 50),
IF(CS_CaseAge__c >= 0, IMAGE('resource/CS_GreenIMG', "green", 20, 50),
IMAGE('resource/CS_RedIMG', "red", 20, 50))))
```

I personally would of written it something like this so that there is only two calls to `CS_CaseAge__c` but this would mean if `CS_CaseAge__c` is negative (which is probably never going to happen) the green image would appear.

```
IF(CS_CaseAge__c >= 25, IMAGE('resource/CS_RedIMG', "red", 20, 50),
IF(CS_CaseAge__c >= 13, IMAGE('resource/CS_YellowIMG', "yellow", 20, 50),
IMAGE('resource/CS_GreenIMG', "green", 20, 50)))
```

Comment: It worked like charm :) Thanks @BarCotter But I need to test its validations as well.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is too large according to the error message. 
The following PDF gives tips to reduce formula size. You have only a few characters extra.

[Tips for Reducing Formula Size](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_formula_size_tipsheet.pdf)

Alternatively, you can use Workflow and field update to update the field accordingly.
Another method is to write a trigger for the same.